# Keyboard shortcut to close miniature windows on taskbar in WIndows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to close miniature windows on Windows taskbar in Windows 8.1 using keyboard shortcut. Is there any?

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> can toggle to taskbar icons. If there any shortcut we want to go File Explorer and press up key and close those open windows.

[image]

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-you-disable-miniature-pop-up-windows-when/e77ada42-29e5-440e-a0be-74e737cf969d?auth=1

Comment: @Hannu Actually I do not want to disable. I wanted to close windows by closing miniature windows.